# Show div with jQuery blind function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and try to show a `div` when the user is clicking on a button. The button is below the text and is suppose to move up and down.

I tried a couple of things but couldn't work it out.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="travel_infobox">

</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="travel_info_button">
<a href="#" target="_blanc">InfoBox</a>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input.show").click(function(){
        $(".travel_infobox").show("blind");
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input.hide").click(function(){
        $(".travel_infobox").hide(blind);
    });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: `.hide(blind);` should be `.hide('blind');`

Comment: other than that it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e9j4U/1/

Comment: Your JS mentions inputs, but you haven't provided said inputs in your HTML example. This would be a naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$(document)ready(function() {});` just one time, it is needed to let jQuery know when the page is fully loaded to run your code.

Then, that `input.show` I suppose there is an input button with `show` class somewhere, otherwise it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input.show").click(function(){
            $(".travel_infobox").show("blind");
        });
        $("input.hide").click(function(){
            $(".travel_infobox").hide("blind");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Where is your show and hide button? So I have added one.

```
<div class="travel_infobox">
Trave info
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="travel_info_button">
<a href="#" target="_blank">InfoBox</a>
</div>
<button id='show'>show</button>
<button id='hide'>hide</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#show").click(function(){
            $(".travel_infobox").show("blind");
        });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#hide").click(function(){
            $(".travel_infobox").hide("blind");
        });
        });
</script>
```